# In iOS9 Interface Builder how can I keep my view below the status bar?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios9

In IB I have this scene in my storyboard [image]

And when ran in simulator it looks exactly like this [image]

Obviously I would like the search bar vertically below the status bar.  How can I accomplish that?  My UITableViewController is embedded inside a UITabBarController btw.

I looked at this technical Q&A QA1797 ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html)), but it talks about iOS 7, and according to this document it should work for UITabBarController, but in my case it does not.

I am using XCode 7.0 (7A220)

UPDATE 1: UITableView not draggable [image]

UPDATE 2: Document Outline view of my Search Scene [image]

UPDATE 3: Size inspector for Table (UITableView) showing that the Size X/Y is not editable (I don't know why), and so I can't reposition the Table [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is embed the initial view controller of your storyboard into a navigation controller.

Steps: 
 1. Select the initial view controller from storyboard. 
 2. Then go to editor -> Embed in Navigation Controller.

Now run and you'll see problem is resolved.
[image]

Comment: Can't embed the initial view controller (UITabBarController) because menu item is dehilighted, but I was able to embed the Search scene (UITableViewController) in the navigation controller.  Problem now is there is a tall empty space at the top.

Comment: Deselecting 'Shows Navigation Bar' in the attributes inspector of the navigation bar fixes the empty space issue.  Still would be great to understand why I wasn't able to fix it naturally, but this works.